# Eclipse “must-have” development tools/plugins for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, favorites

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180939/net-must-have-development-tools), i ask $title.
Which are your favorite PHP coding related Eclipse plugins? Without you can't live? Why?
I list my own plugins of choice:

- [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)
- [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)
- [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

Which are yours?

Comment: might wanna make this a wiki before someone blows up.

Comment: Was thinking of asking a question like this - would love to see some more answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a PHP developper, mainly back-end, I'm using :

- Eclipse PDT for PHP development

  - It's one of the best free IDE for PHP, I think
  - Integration with Xdebug for debugging os pretty nice, too ;-)
- Subversive for SVN integration
- Aptana (plugged into PDT) for HTML/CSS/JS
- Filesync (My project is on a Virtual Machine, which exports its files via a samba share ; this can take lots of time (several minutes) when re-building the project ; Filesync helps a lot with that)

About Eclipse, you can find lots of questions/answers about plugins ; some of them apply to PHP, too.

Aside from Eclipse, I also generally have a lightweight editor (like scite, or vim -- depending on the platform I'm working on) ; it's easier to take notes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a front-end developer, so I can't live without my [Aptana](http://aptana.com/studio/download) plug-in. includes a nice PHP intellisense...Love it!